# Why we use Prototypes

Tags: javascript

i am a total newbie to JS.
My Question is why use prototypes ,
can't we just add a property and give it a default value like this

```
function car(seats,engine,radio){
        this.seats=seats;
        this.engine=engine;
        this.radio='am/fm';
    };
```

Thanks.
As a newbie i searched internet but was unable to fins a simple solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> why use prototypes

To share values, especially functions, across multiple instances.

> can't we just add a property and give it a default value like this

Yes we can, and we should do that for values that are *instance specific*. But for shared values, why duplicate them if we don't have to? (saves memory)

---

In your specific example, all the values seem to be instance specific so there is no need to use prototypes.

Comment: you mean like to not to duplicate the same values say radio for every constructor function??

Comment: As I said, in your specific example, there is not really any gain from using prototypes. See the duplicate question for a better example.